# DatePicker and TimePicker dialogs incorrect padding

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I'm trying to show `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` in my `Activity` using the following code:

```
    private void showDatePickerDialog(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                this,
                listener,
                c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );

        dialog.show();

    }
```

My activity extends from `AppCompatActivity` and I have the following dependencies in my `gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
```

The problem is that the dialogs do not have proper padding:

[image: DatePickerDialog]

[image: TimePickerDialog]

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy J1 with API 22 for testing, my project's `minSdkVersion` is 16 and `targetSdkVersion` 25. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. The same thing happens with Toast messages:

[image: Toast messages]

Edit: I'm using the following Theme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Did you try to update your targetSdk to `27` and the support dependencies to `27.0.2`?

Comment: @chrjs unfortunately no, that didn't solve it

Comment: What theme you are using . Post in question .

Comment: @ADM edited the question including the Theme

Comment: try after remove fitsSystemWindows once.

Comment: @ADM I removed fitsSystemWindows property but it keeps showing incorrectly

Comment: I don't know what exactly the problem . It must be something with theme. Did you tested it multiple devices ?

Comment: @ADM yes, this also happens on an LG Leon (H340) with API 21

Comment: @ADM removing the property from `v21\styles.xml` sorted out the problem, you can post that as an answer so I can accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your style as for above Api 21 in v21\styles.xml.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
</style>
```